# Use a context manager to save an object on exit

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code uses a context manager to store and load variables into files.
However, it's very annoying to have to set the `value` property of what is yielded by the context manager (`loaded.value`).
I would like to

1. Not have to define a new class like `LoadedValue`
2. Set the yielded value of the context manager (`loaded`) to be the value that is saved.

Any way of doing either of those two (as well as other helpful improvements) would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import pickle
from contextlib import contextmanager

class LoadedValue:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "<LoadedValue: {}>".format(self.value)

@contextmanager
def load_manager(load_file="file.pkl"):
    with open(load_file, "rb") as f:
        loaded_object = LoadedValue(pickle.load(f))
    try:
        yield loaded_object
    finally:
        with open(load_file, "wb+") as f:
            pickle.dump(loaded_object.value, f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "test.pkl"
    with open(filename, "wb+") as f:
        pickle.dump(7, f)

    with load_manager(filename) as loaded:
        print(loaded) # >>> <LoadedValue: 7>
        loaded.value = 5 # this is what I have to do
        # loaded = 5  # this is what I want to do

    with load_manager(filename) as loaded:
        print(loaded) # >>> <LoadedValue: 5>
```